# Is there a way to use Spring @Profile annotation at a package level?

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-java-config

I'm trying to put all my bean definitions for a specific profiles together, and would rather not push them all into one giant AppConfig.java class.  I was wondering if there was a way to annotate at a package level using package-info.java and have all configuration files within that package inherit the profile.

I've tried the following in package-info.java:

```
@Profile("test")
package com.system.configuration.test;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
```

But the `@Configuration` classes within the package seem to be used whether it is the "test" profile or not.

Is the only choice to annotate each class individually?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in different way by creating separate `@Configuration` classes for different profiles:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
@ComponentScan("com.system.configuration.test")
public class TestProfile {
}
```

And then on your main configuration class you need to do imports:

```
@Configuration
@Import(TestProfile.class)
public class MainConfiguration {
}
```

Comment: not working, if the "TestProfile" config is under MainConfiguration package.